# Visual studio 2015 c++ and assembly not building

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2015

I recently wanted to start learning assembly, but I have been having some problem setting up my project to build.

What I want to have is a C++ and assembly project, but it is currently not working. My assembly code shown below builds just fine:

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data

.code

main proc

    mov rax, 8

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess

main endp

end
```

but the moment I add a cpp file to my project I get a load of linker errors:

```
void ToDo()
{
    int i = 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AssemblyTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_init_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_init_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INITW
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_error_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function _vsprintf_s_l
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_error_.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wmakepath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wsplitpath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wcscpy_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_GetModuleHandleW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(_pdblkup_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_LoadLibraryExW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE__ * __cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE__@@XZ)
1>C:\Users\***\Desktop\AssemblyTest\x64\Debug\AssemblyTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with my setup and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're linking your project with only part of the C runtime (CRT) libary, `msvcrtd.lib`. You also need to link with the libraries `vcruntimed.lib` and `ucrtd.lib`. The former is part of Visual Studio 2015 itself while the later is part of the Windows 10 SDK that was installed along Visual Studio. Normally C++ projects automatically link with these libraries, but apparently your project is setup not to.

You may be following instructions meant for an older version of Visual Studio which only required linking with one CRT library file. This changed due to [a refactoring of the CRT with Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx).

Comment: Or with none of it at all, e.g. `/NODEFAULTLIB`